# in does not find substring in string

Tags: substring

why is 'helo' not found in 'hello'?  I have tried hello and he and both of those are found.  I'm very confused.

tr1 = "hello"
find_this = "helo"
if find_this in str1:
    print find_this, " is been found in ", str1
else:
    print find_this, " is not found in ", str1

Comment: and why it shout be found? in hello you will find
hel, hell, hello, el, ello, lo, but helo is not substring of hello

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. 

Please specify your language in tags or in the question at least. It's Python, I guess?

Comment: cause he is searching the entire string 'helo', he doesn't take the spelling mistake into account. It wouldn't find 'hllo' anymore.

Comment: Because there is no *helo* in *hello*. I'm not sure what you expect, but you can't do a simple `in` for a value that doesn't exist and magically find it. It won't find `hllo` in there, either. *he* exists (as the first two letters), *hello* is an exact match. You'll find you can also match *hell* and *ello* and *ll* and *llo* and *lo* and *o*, all of which are actually in the string.

Answer (score 0):

"helo" is not a [substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) of "hello". (It is a [subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence)).

"hello" contains the following substrings: "h", "e", "l", "o", "he", "el", "ll", "lo", "hel", "ell", "llo", "hell", "ello" and "hello".

The `in` operator looks for substrings, therefore it cannot find "helo" in "hello".

Answer (score 0):

The question is asked to you now, besides computing.

**Is 'helo' a part of 'hello' ?** Is 'helo' contained in 'hello', no it is not !

```
'ello' is.
'llo' is.
'lo' is.
'o' is.

'h' is.
'he' is.
'hel' is.
'hell' is.

**'helo' is clearly not !** a substring of 'hello'
```